# Configuring remote schema with IntelliJ GraphQL plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, graphql, webstorm

I am trying to use the [IntelliJ GraphQL plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/js-graphql-intellij-plugin#configuration), and my project has a GraphQL config file, but the plugin doesn't appear to be finding anything:

[image]

This is the schema file:

```js
require('dotenv').config()

const SHOPIFY_GRAPHQL_API_ENDPOINT = `https://${
  process.env.PUBLIC_STORE_DOMAIN ?? 'unknown'
}/api/2023-01/graphql.json`

const CONFIG_GRAPHQL_CLIENT = {
  plugins: [
    'typescript',
    'typescript-operations',
    'typescript-graphql-request',
  ],
}

/** @type {import('graphql-config').IGraphQLConfig } */
module.exports = {
  projects: {
    contentful: {
      documents: './src/cms/Contentful/**/*.graphql',
      schema: {
        [process.env.CONTENTFUL_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT]: {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${
              process.env.CONTENTFUL_PREVIEW_API_ACCESS_TOKEN ?? ''
            }`,
          },
        },
      },
      extensions: {
        codegen: {
          generates: {
            'src/cms/Contentful/client.generated.ts': {
              ...CONFIG_GRAPHQL_CLIENT,
              config: {
                typesPrefix: 'Contentful',
                documentMode: 'documentNode',
                dedupeFragments: true,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    shopify: {
      documents: './src/ecom/Shopify/**/*.graphql',
      schema: {
        [SHOPIFY_GRAPHQL_API_ENDPOINT]: {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',
            'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token':
              process.env.PUBLIC_STOREFRONT_API_TOKEN,
          },
        },
      },
      extensions: {
        codegen: {
          generates: {
            'src/ecom/Shopify/client.generated.ts': {
              ...CONFIG_GRAPHQL_CLIENT,
              config: {
                documentMode: 'documentNode',
                dedupeFragments: true,
                typesPrefix: 'Shopify',
                enumPrefix: false, // Needed to match enums from TDG
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

The plugin's docs mentions using environment variables like `${THIS}` but of course JS, ESLint, etc, doesn't like that at all since it's, you know, not valid code. I also tried pasting in all the actual values of the environment variables to test it but that didn't appear to make any difference.